# java coding confusion about String args[] and String[] args

Tags: java

I am new in programming with Java and I am confused about the following two statements:

```
public static void main(String args[])
```

and

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Are they same? If not, how are they different from each other?

Comment: No difference, although IMO the latter is preferred.

Comment: The only difference is the place where the brackets are

Comment: The real fun begins when you using multidimensional arrays String[] strings[] = new String[1][1]; is really nice.

Comment: @larlin only if one is a sociopath O:-)

Comment: @mcfinnigan Now I got some inspiration from the answer bellow. New improved sociopath java array: String[] strings[], stringss[][] = new String[1][1][1]; Isn't the world great?

Answer (score 5):

There is no semantic difference between the two forms, the only difference is stylistic.

Answer (score 3):

They mean the same thing. The second form is generally preferred, as it puts the array declaration with the type declaration. By the way, there's nothing special about this appearing in the main() method, arrays can be declared both ways any place in your code.

Answer (score 3):

While it's true for single statements there **IS** a difference in case you define more than one variable:

```
String[] foo1, foo2; // both variables are of type String[]
String bar1[], bar2; // here they're not. But you really shouldn't do this, causes
                     // unnecessary confusion
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are the same, yet the convention is to write `String[] args` as `String[]` is the type.

Answer (score 1):

Both have exactly the same meaning. However, the first is unconventional and should not be used, because it splits type information. It's a holdover from C.

Answer (score 1):

Its also basically the same as

```
public static void main(String... args)
```

which is what I prefer.